# how to delete KeyChainItemData and genericPasswordQuery items from iOS keychain

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I have been having some troubles with my keychain, I think mainly because I was not aware of how it worked when I first started using it, I tried several variations of adding data and strings passwords etc into my keychain thinking that when I deleted the app from my device it would clear the keychain... I now know this is not how the keychain works so was hoping I could get some help clearing up the junk that is in my keychain now.

The thing is I am now trying to pass some information to my keychain but am receiving the following error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain], /Users/imac/Documents/Iphone applications/Keystone/Keystone/KeychainItemWrapper.m:268
2013-07-23 11:07:46.086 Keystone[2769:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'
```

This error happens when I try to pass some info into the keychainwrapper I have declares as illustrated in the code below.

```
[keychainItem setObject:@"somestringhere" forKey: (__bridge id)kSecAttrService];
```

I think the code is actually fine, because I think the current junk in my keychain is preventing me from correctly adding to the new items to the keychain. I implement the wrapper like this

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"gena" accessGroup:@"KeyStone.com.WHATWHAT.GenericKeychainSuite"];
```

I can see this in my debug area.

[image]

As you can see **KeyChainItemData** and **genericPasswordQuery** are already in my keychain with 6 - 5 objects?! weird.
From that I have tried to clear my keychain using the following code...

```
[keychainItem resetKeychainItem];
```

The only issue being is that this dose nothing to help me. So I was wondering what I might need to do in order to delete these **KeyChainItemData** and **genericPasswordQuery** entries that seem to be in my keychain preventing me from adding the correct entries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
So from doing further research when I declare KeychainItemWrapper thats when all of those values are showing themselves in my debugging area, however after trying the same code on a different device that has not had any keychain development done on it it still showed those same values. So I figure its not on the device its got to be something else... hopefully that makes sense.. I will continue trying to find a solution.

Comment: Take a look at this previous post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086085/how-to-delete-all-keychain-items-accessible-to-an-app

Comment: Okay tried implementing this but it still didn't work. all of those values are still there at the end. I am going to double check it all to see what var types are currently in there.

Comment: I still cannot access or delete the data found inside KeyChainItemData and genericPasswordQuery dose anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this short step by step example on [useyourloaf.com](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/03/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html)

It covers simple iPhone keychain access. It has examples to search, create, update and delete an item from the keychain.

You might also want to look at the Apple Developer [Keychain Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html). The coommand you are looking for is SecItemDelete.

Comment: Okay thank you I am going to look up both links now and go through them slowly. I will let you know how I go.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against using KeychainItemWrapper. After working with the KeychainItemWrapper for multiple projects I kept finding multiple bugs and edge cases that weren't considered so I created my own simpler wrapper for accessing the Keychain https://github.com/reidmain/FDKeychain

It works very similar to NSDictionary with just setValue: and objectForKey: methods.