# Analytic data not showing up with Bluemix Mobile Application Security

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm using MAS with a Node.js app and a hybrid (not ios8 native) mobile application. I can make authenticated calls to my Node.js server, but I'm noticing that I have nothing showing up in Analytics. Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your iPhone's keychain? There can be some issues with Bluemix analytics due to lingering stale keychain data. Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142774/reset-an-iphone-apps-keychain) for code to clear the keychain.

Comment: Did you see that I'm using a hybrid app, not native. Also, I'm testing with the simulator, not a real device.

Comment: Yes, I did. is the same issue present for both iOS and Android? Does it make a difference if you use a real device? Have you tried the Reset Content and Settings option in the iOS simulator?

Comment: Sorry if that reply was snarky. :) Reset on iOS sim and tested again. Tested on an Android device. So far, nothing in the analytics. If there is a 'buffer' in terms of how long it takes for things to show up, let me know. I'd expect it to show rather quickly, but maybe it takes longer?